# Rails Heroku App displays 404 error with strange iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, http-status-code-404

My website has suddenly started to display a strange 404 error with this iframe on the page - the home page works fine but all other links display this 404 page.

Page Not Found
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please try the following:

If you typed the page address in the Address bar, make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Click the Back button in your browser to try another link.
Use a search engine like Google to look for information on the Internet.

```
<iframe src="http://dsnextgen.com/?domainname=www.re-work.co&amp;a_id=101686&amp;session_token=AG06ipDtdI2uTssAri4vraxFJ-j9XzRtaQoTCLv7n9iItLgCFYxhwgodmxMACRgEcaZIMXCeshldeMP39IwE" frameborder="0" height="800" scrolling="auto" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Nothing has changed except purchasing an SSL certificate from my domain host - domain.com.

I have read about this being a hack but cant find any solutions anywhere.

Any ideas?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: www.re-work.co - works ok for me.

Comment: Correct but if you try to go anywhere else i.e. www.re-work.co/tech

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing some kind of frame based domain forwarding here - in fact, you are.

You should change your DNS entry www.re-work.co to be a CNAME entry to your application ie. disrupt-production.herokuapp.com and then add www.re-work.co as a custom domain on your Heroku application.

This will ensure that all your links show as www.re-work.co and no the herokuapp.com URLs (when you mouse over your navigation links).

Comment: Thanks John, I understand what you are saying but the domain was brought from Domain.com and they have some strange DNS settings so this doesnt actually work. I have attached some screen shots of the DNS settings.

Comment: I think you need to remove the pointer entry so the www.re-work.co DNS entry is picked up.

Comment: Dont you need the pointer to point to www. and then the cname with www. point to Heroku? You can see from the above screen shots that I have everything set up correctly but now www.re-work.co doesn't work and /tech still has the strange 404 error.

Comment: When i do an nslookup of your domain I still get the old entry, might have to wait for the change to propogate now.

Comment: Okay, I've never of heard of pointer either, I assumed it's the same as forward which is what I do when using Go Daddy to point to the www. cname.

Comment: That's all working now as I'd expect - the 'pointer' is working and www. is resolving to the CNAME too.